# Loading items in Combobox

Tags: vb.net

I am working on a project and the problem that I have is; the items of my combobox are being loaded from the database table(one field); the table has more than 1000 records:

how can I load these records(one field) as items by giving a limit of 50 while allowing the user who wants to see all of the records through the combobox to see them but still by a group of 50?

which event can be the best for loading items to the combobox? textchanged, click....

I was thinking to use the vertical scroll bar so that when the user is at the end of the displayed items the next 50 will be loaded and if he is on the first and scrolls up the previous 50 will be loaded:problems with this way of thinking are:

1. when the user typed some caracter from the word that he wanna select
   from the items' list if it is not loaded yet from the DB he will be
   obliged to type the whole word
2. I don't know which event is raised
   when scroll bar of reaches the end or is at the beginning

Is there any other way to do that?

Comment: if you have the memory you can store it in a data structure , if not you will have to use by row number

Comment: I'm afraid that your question doesn't really make sense.  Are you saying that you only want to load 50 items at a time but give the user some way to change which 50 are displayed?  How exactly do you envision this working from the user's perspective?  Maybe you would be better off using the auto-complete functionality that is built into the `TextBox `and `ComboBox` controls.

Comment: It makes sense since you've understood what I want.Are you saying that you only want to load 50 items at a time but give the user some way to change which 50 are displayed? the answer is YES!